# UIView transition - flip two subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

In a UIView subclass (mainView) I do this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:firstView
                        toView:secondView
                      duration:3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }
     ];
```

However, the entire view flips. I just want to flip firstView and secondView, which are subviews of mainView. How do I fix this?

Comment: Found the answer [here][1]. The subviews need a container view.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524048/how-to-flip-an-individual-uiview-without-flipping-the-parent-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
 completion:NULL
```

Comment: can you provide the complete statement? this only looks like two options of the method call

Comment: [UIView transitionFromView:oldView toView:newView  
                  duration:1.0 
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                  completion:NULL];