# Flip view itself using animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using UIView animateWithDuration method to flip the UILabelView itself but it doesn't show any animation until I provide some code in the animations block. Here's the code.

No effect

```
[UIView animateWithDurations:5. delay:0. 
options:UIViewAnimationOPtionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations: ^{} 
completion:nil];
```

Fades the View

```
[UIView animateWithDurations:5. delay:0.
 options:UIViewAnimationOPtionTransitionFlipFromLeft
animations: ^{self.lblEvent.alpha = 0.5;} completion:nil];
```

My question is when the options parameter will effect?

I tried the below code too but it flips the view and removes from the controller. Can't I provide the same view?

```
[UIView transitionFromView: self.lblEvent toView:self.lblEvent
duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOPtionTransitionFlipFromLeft
completion:nil];
```

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524048/how-to-flip-an-individual-uiview-without-flipping-the-parent-view?rq=1

Comment: No, In the above link the flipping is not for the whole controller but only for subview of a controller.

Comment: you want to flip only uilabel right?

Comment: Yes, I just want to flip uilabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:your_view_to_animate duration:1. options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom) animations:^{
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Great. It works. but one more question whats the use of options in animateWithDuration?

Comment: I'm not really sure about those :)

Comment: animateWithDuration this method will slow down animation time based upon input followed by it/