# iOS: How to flip a UIView about more than 180 degree and view the backside?

Tags: ios, uiview, 3d, rotation, uikit

is it possible to flip a UIView about the x or y axes, such that it flips entirely over and you can see the "backside" of the view? I gather that UIKit is based on OpenGL ES, and so there is the question of whether they implemented layers using two-sided triangles...

Answer (score 2):

To flip into a view controller:

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To flip out of it:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

If you want to flip only views you can put the two views you want to flip inside an unnamed view with the same size and link the IBOutlet UIView *newView,*oldView; to the views and put the new view on top

```
bool a = NO;

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender 
{
    if (a == NO) {
        [UIView transitionFromView:oldView toView:newView  
                  duration:1.0 
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                  completion:NULL];
        a = YES; // a = !a;
    }
    else {
        [UIView transitionFromView:newView toView:oldView  
                  duration:1.0 
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                  completion:NULL];
        a = NO; // a = !a;
    }
}
```

Source: [How to flip an individual UIView (without flipping the parent view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524048/how-to-flip-an-individual-uiview-without-flipping-the-parent-view)

---

You can check this awesome custom controllers:

- [iOS flip transform](https://github.com/Dillion/iOS-Flip-Transform)
- [JDFlipNumberView](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDFlipNumberView)
- [ADFlip Transition](https://github.com/adamdebono/ADFlipTransition)
- [FlipCard Navigation View](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/FlipCardNavigationView)
- [zbgridConroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/zbgridcontroller)
- [cmscoinview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cmscoinview)
- [mpflipviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mpflipviewcontroller)