# flip two subview doesn't work continuosly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have found a solution here [How to flip an individual UIView (without flipping the parent view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524048/how-to-flip-an-individual-uiview-without-flipping-the-parent-view?rq=1)

but it seems that this doesn't work for me. In Interface Builder i have set up all with a uiview and inside that two uiviews, with the same size and the first view to be shown on top and i have created three outlets for this 3 views.

In viewDidLoad:

```
 [self.view addSubview:self.contentView]
 [self.contentView addSubview:firstView]
 [self.contentView addSubview:secondView]
```

i have a uigesture. When the user taps the screen, the IBAction executes the flip:

```
-(IBAction)flip:(id *)sender
{
 if(faceUp){

       // execute transition from firstview to second
 }else{

      //execute transition from secondview to first
 }

 faceUp = !faceUp;
}
```

this work perfectly the first time i click and the flips happens from the first to second, then if i tap again the flip starts and then it ends with nothing, the view disappears and remains the container view showing nothing because its color is set to clear.
How can i resolve this?

This is the controller with the tap gesture method and the three outlets:

```
  #import "ContactViewController.h"
  #import "InfoContactView.h"
  #import "ImageLogoView.h"

  @interface ContactViewController ()
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet InfoContactView *contactInfoView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ImageLogoView *imageLogoView;
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL faceUp;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *parentView;


  @end

 @implementation ContactViewController

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
  }
 return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  self.parentView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.parentView];
  [self.parentView addSubview:self.contactInfoView];
    [self.parentView addSubview:self.imageLogoView];


    self.faceUp = NO;
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)setFaceUp:(BOOL)faceUp
{
    _faceUp = faceUp;

}

-(void)setParentView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    _parentView =parentView;
}

-(void)setContactInfoView:(InfoContactView *)contactInfoView
{
 _contactInfoView = contactInfoView;
}

-(void)setImageLogoView:(ImageLogoView *)imageLogoView
{
  _imageLogoView = imageLogoView;
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {




  if (self.faceUp == NO) {
      [UIView transitionFromView:self.imageLogoView toView:self.contactInfoView
                        duration:1.5
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                      completion:NULL];
      NSLog(@"Pass from logo to info : imageLogoView = %@",self.imageLogoView.description);

      NSLog(@"dettagli = %@",self.contactInfoView);



  }
   else if(self.faceUp == YES){
      [UIView transitionFromView:self.contactInfoView toView:self.imageLogoView
                        duration:1.5
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                      completion:NULL];

      NSLog(@"Pass from info to logo: imageLogoView = %@",self.imageLogoView.description);

      NSLog(@"dettagli = %@",self.contactInfoView);

  }

  self.faceUp = !self.faceUp;

 }




 @end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's *inside* the if/else statement in your `-flip` method? To me it looks like the reference to `firstView` is set to `nil` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Mischa i have edited the initial post adding the entire controller with the flip method inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reconstruct your problem in Xcode. I added some lines of code to log `parentView`'s subviews before and after each transition. Judging from the logs your initial view's frame (`self.imageLogoView`) is reset to a width and height of 0 at some point:

```
<UIView: 0x8b84310; frame = (159.5 284.5; 0 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b84370>>
```

which means it is still there but you just can't see it.

Apparently **Autolayout is responsible for resizing the view's frame**. If you deactivate Autolayout for your View Controller the transition works just fine.
(To deactivate Autolayout select the respective View Controller in your Storyboard. In the right column *(Utilities)* go to the first tab  [image: first tab] and deselect the checkbox *"Use Autolayout"*. [image: use Autolayout])

On the other hand Autolayout is said to be a nice thing or at least it is promoted by Apple as such. So if you *want* to use Autolayout you have to take care of your view's frames yourself by adding appropriate constraints. First select your `imageLogoView` and add constraints for width and height by checking the respective boxes as shown in the screenshot below. Then do the same with your `contactInfoView`.

[image: Screenshot Xcode Constraints]

That should do the trick.